# Let $S=\{Re(f(z))+Im(f(z))|z\in \Omega\}.$ Which of the following necessarily correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function on $\mathbb C$ and let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb C$. Let $S=\{Re(f(z))+Im(f(z))|z\in \Omega\}.$ Which of the following necessarily correct?

(A) $S$ is an open subset in $\mathbb R$

(B)$S$ is a closed subset in $\mathbb R$

(C)$S$ is an open subset in $\mathbb C$

(D) $S$ is a discrete subset in $\mathbb R$

My attempt.
Obviously, (C) is false since $S=\{Re(f(z))+Im(f(z))|z\in \Omega\}\subset \mathbb R$. Any subset of $\mathbb R$ is not open in $\mathbb C$. Consider an entire function $f(z)=z=re^{it},0\leq t \leq 2\pi, 0\leq r <1$. Let $\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\},$ $|Re(f(z))+Im(f(z))|=|x+y|=|r\cos t+r\sin t| .$ Using derivative, I can prove that Maximum of $|r\cos t+r\sin t|=r\sqrt{2}<\sqrt{2}. $ So, $S$ is open, Not closed. not discrete. Hence, (A) is the answer. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hints:*

1. The real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic functions.
2. A non-constant harmonic function is an open map. See: [Prove that a harmonic function is an open map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371473/549397)